# Can Ahri's ultimate cause her Orb of Deception to trigger more than twice?

Tags: league-of-legends

Ahri's Orb of Deception goes out linearly to hit the foe once as it flies out and once more when it comes back. Is it possible to use Ahri's ult to "flash" back and forth to essentially increase the number of times it hits a foe?

Comment: If it works the same as Sivir's boomerang, the damage will never proc more than twice, no matter what.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

League of Legends has two types of blinks - "true" blinks, like the summoner spell flash, and "Blinkdash"es, skills like Poppy's Heroic Charge, Xin Zhao's Audacious Charge, and Ahri's Spirit Rush.

The big difference is that blinkdashes don't remove the champion from the field. If you Blinkdash through a skillshot, you will still get hit by the skill shot.

In Ahri's case, this means as soon as she tries to dash over her orb, she will simply pick it back up instead.

What you propose *would* be possible with the summoner spell Flash (similar feats have been done with Sivir's Boomerang Blade), but the paltry damage is probably not worth wasting flash's long cooldown on.

Comment: and what if Lee Sin get 1st Orb -> get 2nd Orb -> uses Q on Ahri > get 3rd Orb?

Comment: And then Ahri flashes and Lee Sin gets fourth orb. :) Would the 2nd - 4th orb all be true damage... that's a lot of damage 0.0 Almost 250 magic and 750 true damage late game. Forget Chogath! We got flash dancing Ahri :)